# How to authenticate by mail using devise and grape in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api, devise, ruby-grape

■What I want to realize

When a mail address and password are sent by grape, an authentication mail is sent to the mail address by dvise.
(Using API instead of View.)

■What can be done

- About devise, I can send authentication mail using View with reference to the following page.
  https://github.com/plataformatec/devise#getting-started
- About grape, I can reference and register user information with the code as below.

  ```
  resource :users do
      get ':user_name', jbuilder:'user' do
           User.find_by(user_name: params[:user_name])
      end

      post do
          User.create(user_name: params[:user_name], password: params[:password], mail: params[:mail])
      end
  end
  ```

■Unknown point

1. I do not know how to cooperate with devise and grape.
2. I do not know what kind of action on the grape side will cause the devise side to send authentication mails.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you meant confirmation email by authentication email

You can `user.send_confirmation_instructions`

[Reference](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/plataformatec/devise/master/Devise/Models/Confirmable#send_confirmation_instructions-instance_method)